# Drupal Registration Form Custom Fields Disappear after OG upgrade (Related to drupal_render)

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, organic-groups

I'm using Drupal 7 with several modules to support an active member network site. After upgrading one of the modules, all custom fields disappeared on the user registration page.

I created a custom registration page template and tested the form to see where the breakage was, and it looks like the module is incorrectly changing the permissions on all fields, breaking the drupal_render() function for this form. Since I really need this latest version of the module (Organic Groups), I'm willing to hack the solution to this problem a bit.

What I've come up with is to custom render the form, but I need a bit of help. Is it possible to render a form field by field at the Theme level? Or, is there a way to render to form while stopping permissions from hiding all the fields?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A few questions for a better answer.  Is this Drupal 6 or Drupal 7?  There were a lot of changes with how custom fields are handled in Drupal 7, so knowing which you are using will help isolate the conflict.
Are you using any profile modules, or were these custom fields attached in another way?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Drupal 7 with the standard CCK fields. No other custom fields modules, but I am using Field Access.